# How make friendly Expression Blend and Caliburn.Micro WPF

Tags: wpf, caliburn.micro, expression-blend

I'm try to change my View Model for my Application. Use MVVM and Caliburn.Micro. But when I try open my project in Expression Blend for Visual Studio 2012 I get an error about my Caliburn.Micro dll. I don't see my view window in Expression Blend IDE and have many errors. How make friendly Expression Blend and Caliburn.Micro WPF.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

there are directions on www.caliburnmicro.com about setting up design time support since you don't have it configuration at present.  It also appears that you a reference issue Message.Attach doesn't appear to be recognized.  Doesn't matter if you are using Window, Page, UserControl fyi

```
 <Window 
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
  xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:CaliburnDesignTimeData.ViewModels"
  xmlns:cal="clr-namespace:Caliburn.Micro;assembly=Caliburn.Micro.Platform"
  mc:Ignorable="d" 
  d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=vm:MainPageViewModel, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}" 
  cal:Bind.AtDesignTime="True">
```